# unable to delete a last file in folder while deleting folder using php

Tags: php

I am calling my php function from some other website which delete a folder on my server in background.

This is a function which I am using to delete a folder.

```
public static function remove($dir)
        {
            if (is_dir($dir)) {
                $diropen = opendir($dir);
                while($d = readdir($diropen)) {
                    if ($d!= '.' && $d != '..') {
                        self::remove($dir . "/$d");
                    }
                }
                @rmdir($dir);
            } elseif (is_file($dir)) {
                @unlink($dir);
            }
        }
```

If I am having three files in folder then it deletes only two and unable to delete last file or unlink fails on last file.

If I am having two files then it deletes only one file.

I have checked writable permission using `is_writable` it is true for all files.

Can somebody please help me out. or how to debug this behavior as this function is getting called in background.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Read the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php  "/* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */"

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Is there way to debug unlink error as it is not working at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my directory was open in some other function , so I `closedir` my folder and then above function working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function delete_directory($target) {
         if (is_dir($target))
           $dir_handle = opendir($target);
     if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
     while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                     unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                else
                     delete_directory($target.'/'.$file);
           }
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
     rmdir($target);
     return true;
}

?>
```

use closedir and you'll be fine.